# Insert Missing Columns on All Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search all of the headers on each of my worksheets, and if any are missing from an array, insert columns and put those headers in.

Here is a code I found online and modified.

If more than one heading is missing, it just replaces the added headers. E.g. Suite/Unit and Logo are both missing, so it inserts the column for Suite/Unit, and then replaces it with the header Logo.

Also, I need it to work for all worksheets in the workbook.

```
For Each Word In Array("Company", "First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Category", "Address", "Suite or Unit?", "Suite/Unit", "City", "Province", "Postal Code", "Phone", "Fax", "Website", "Service Areas", "Logo") 
Set aRange = Range("a1:iv1").Find(What:=Word, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
If aRange Is Nothing Then
Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)=Word
End If
Next Word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following where a loop of the Worksheet collection ensure all Worksheets are dealt with. Missing columns are added to the end.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim word As Variant, ws As Worksheet, aRange As Range
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each word In Array("Company", "First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Category", "Address", "Suite or Unit?", "Suite/Unit", "City", "Province", "Postal Code", "Phone", "Fax", "Website", "Service Areas", "Logo")
            Set aRange = ws.Range("A1:IV1").Find(What:=word, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
            If aRange Is Nothing Then
                ws.Cells(1, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1) = word
            End If
        Next word
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much :)